# Javascript Push new value in array with indexs

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, extjs

I am trying to add a new message in existing javascript object *initialData*. might be having previous warning messages as well but below code is throwing error as 'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference'. 
Defining as *initialData['warnings'] ='';* before this below code also not solving this issue.

Thanks for generous suggestions and i changed the code as below but still getting error ' Unable to get property push of undefined or null reference'

** Modified Code**

```
var initialData = false;
initialData.warnings = [];
initialData.warnings.push({
                        title: ' Major Warning'
                        ,msg:  'This is a major warning'
        });
```

Could someone please point out the issue and how to fix it.

***Soultion****

Assigned existing values in array and push the new value in array. After that assigned array to object.

```
var warnings = [] ;
warnings = initialData.warning;
warnings.push({
                        title: ' Major Warning'
                        ,msg:  'This is a major warning'
        });

initialData.warning = warnings;
```

Comment: Wow so many answers for one question, other questions are unanswered ...great !!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues, the first being that you are initializing to an empty string instead of an empty array:

```
initialData.warnings = [];
```

Then you have a syntax error as @Rohit pointed out:

```
initialData.warnings.push({
    title: ' Major Warning'
   ,msg:  'This is a major warning'] <--- INVALID BRACKET
});
```

Remove the bracket and it should work fine:

```
initialData.warnings.push({
    title: ' Major Warning'
   ,msg:  'This is a major warning'
});
```

Side note: it's best to use dot notation for known properties and bracket notation for dynamic properties

Comment: Changed the code and updated the question but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to initialise the array:

```
initialData.warnings = [];
```

Also as @Rob said for invalid bracket.

```
initialData.warnings.push({
    title: ' Major Warning'
   ,msg:  'This is a major warning'] <--- INVALID BRACKET
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in Javascript there is no Array with indexes concept. It is called a Object which have pairs of Key and Value. you can not use push method in object.

```
var obj={a:"A"}; // this is javascript object act like index array
obj.b= "B"; // first method
obj['c']= "C"; // second method
console.log(obj);

//iterate values and keys from javascript object
for(var i in obj){
    console.log(i); // console key
    console.log(obj[i]); // console value of key
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
var initialData = false;
```

This definition is making `initialData` as `boolean` datatype. It should be `Object` datatype, to have `warnings` as its property. So definition should define it as an Object like this:

```
var initialData = {};
```

Full Code:

```js
var initialData = {};
    initialData.warnings = [];
    initialData.warnings.push({
                            title: ' Major Warning'
                            ,msg:  'This is a major warning'
            });
console.log(initialData);
```

Comment: No, push is not working on object. Push is meant for array only. Somehow need to find method to add value dynamically for object.

Comment: You are right push works on array only. That's why `warnings` is defined as an array. But `initialData` should be an Object.Because only object can have properties like `warnings` in your case for `initialData`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove bracket after **msg:'This is a major warning'**

```
initialData['warnings'].push({
                        title: ' Major Warning'
                        ,msg:  'This is a major warning'
        });
```